# Object required in validation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate code in javascript. Here is my code:

```
if(document.getElementById("name").value == ""){
    alert("Name is a required field");
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
    return false;
}
```

`name` is id in my html page:

```
<div class="app-form-box">
  {% if review %}
    {% if not review.name %}
      <input type="text" alt="" onkeyup="return validateField(name)" tabindex="2" name="name" id="name" class="disabled inputtxtlarge" onfocus="highlightInput(this.id)" onblur="return (!validateField(name) || unhighlightInput(this.id))" maxlength="50" value="{{name|moonescape}}" disabled="disabled"/><span> </span>
    {% else %}
      <input type="text" alt="" onkeyup="return validateField(name)" tabindex="2" name="name" id="name" class="inputtxtlarge" onfocus="highlightInput(this.id)" onblur="return (!validateField(name) || unhighlightInput(this.id))" maxlength="50" value="{{name|moonescape}}"/><span> </span>
    {% endif %}
  {% else %}
    <input type="text" alt="" onkeyup="return validateField(name)" tabindex="2" name="name" id="faname" class="inputtxtlarge" onfocus="highlightInput(this.id)" onblur="return (!validateField(name) || unhighlightInput(this.id))" maxlength="50" value="{{name|moonescape}}"/><span> </span>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="servererror">
    {% if form_errors.name %}
      * {{ form_errors.name|join:"| " }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

But I am getting `OBJECT REQUIRED`. Please suggest how to put check in js file for this.  Thanks

Comment: I did changes but same .Please help

Comment: This looks like server page error rather than javascript error.

Comment: What server language is that?